# Android handling the response from a rest webservice call

Tags: java, android, web-services

Hi am creating an android application in which am consuming rest webservices.

The webservice calling and the getting the response from webservice is OK.
It was working fine.

I just want to know how can we properly handle the reponse we got from the android web service.

As the response to webservice call,am getting an `xml` string that was the representation an ArrayList of Objects say `List< Student >` . Now i just want to know how we can convert this xml format as response am getting to an ArrayList say `List< Student >` at the client side (means on android platform).

Answer (score 1):

Implement [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html). You will find a decent tutorial [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_Serialization_Example_%28Java%29).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I replied too soon. Normally, you'd use an xml parser (http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) to parse the response and create your objects as required. I use  a REST service that returns `json`. I use a similar approach. But json parsing is much simpler and built into java.